# Как сделать кнопку переключения тем?

Tags: html

я не плохо разбираюсь в коде, пожалуйста помогите!!!!!! Каак сделать такую кнопку? HTML, которая переключала бы темы?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот [оригинал](https://encycolorpedia.ru/808080), на который я равняюсь

Comment: интересно кто и зачем закрыл вопрос, да было 5 похожих вопросов, но тут вроде бы подкрадывался ответ, может не окончательный но тем не менее

Comment: @DaniilLoban, вопрос закрыли, потому что он явно не по теме. Автор фактически просит сделать кнопку за него. Хотя можно было и избежать закрытия, просто переформулировав вопрос

Comment: @Voprositel этот вопрос можно будет увидеть, найти тем кто будет искать подобное решение? собсвенно говоря "Как сделать кнопку переключения тем?" это моя переформулировка которую я сделал на этот вопрос после того как дал ответ, изначально вопрос звучал что-то типа "как сделать такую кнопку?" у автора около 5 похожих вопросов удивительно что они остались открыты.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, как мне самому когда-то написали, закрытый вопрос ≠ удалённый

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const lamp = document.querySelector('#clrLamp');
const btn = document.querySelector('#bg');
const body = document.querySelector('body');

let lampIsOff = true;
const change = () => {
  lampIsOff = !lampIsOff; // инвретировать состояние
  // изменить стили в svg
  lamp.style= lampIsOff ? "" : "fill: rgb(255, 255, 144);"
  // поменять цвет фона 
  body.classList.toggle('bgcolor');
}

btn.addEventListener('click', change, false )
```

```css
#bg {
    left: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
    top: 1em;
    opacity: .8;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    height: 3.5em;
    width: 3.5em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    font-size: .8em;
    z-index: 100;
}
button, input {
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
}
button, input[type="submit"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
body, button, input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: "Open Sans",Roboto,Ubuntu,Tahoma,Geneva,sans-serif;
}

#bg svg, footer img, footer svg {
    height: 2.5em;
}

.bgcolor {
  background: #333333;
}
```

```html
<body>
<button id="bg" style="background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140);"><svg viewBox="0 0 13.31 23" version="1"><path fill="#fff" d="M8.86 18.43c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.3v-.3c0-.18-.12-.32-.28-.32h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.18-.28.35v.3c0 .17.12.3.28.3zm0 1.34c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.3v-.3c0-.18-.12-.32-.28-.32h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.14-.28.3v.3c0 .18.12.32.28.32zm0 1.37c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.32v-.3c0-.16-.12-.3-.28-.3h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.14-.28.3v.3c0 .18.12.32.28.32zm-.76.46c-.25.53-.8.9-1.44.9-.63 0-1.2-.38-1.46-.9h2.9z"></path><path id="clrLamp" fill="#222" d="M6.66.5C3.26.5.5 3.26.5 6.66c0 1.12.3 2.16.82 3.07 1.5 2.72 1.9 4.25 2.16 5.73.2 1.24.5 1.53 1.43 1.53h3.54c.95 0 1.23-.3 1.44-1.57.25-1.48.65-3 2.16-5.73.5-.9.82-1.94.82-3.06C12.86 3.27 10.16.5 6.7.5z"></path></svg></button>
</body>
```

Вот переделанный пример:

```html
<body>
<button id="bg" style="background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140);left: 1em; padding: .5em; top: 1em; opacity: .8; display: inline-block; position: fixed; height: 3.5em; width: 3.5em; border-radius: 50%; font-size: .8em; z-index: 100; margin: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; cursor: pointer;"><svg style="height: 2.5em;" viewBox="0 0 13.31 23" version="1"><path fill="#fff" d="M8.86 18.43c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.3v-.3c0-.18-.12-.32-.28-.32h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.18-.28.35v.3c0 .17.12.3.28.3zm0 1.34c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.3v-.3c0-.18-.12-.32-.28-.32h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.14-.28.3v.3c0 .18.12.32.28.32zm0 1.37c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.32v-.3c0-.16-.12-.3-.28-.3h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.14-.28.3v.3c0 .18.12.32.28.32zm-.76.46c-.25.53-.8.9-1.44.9-.63 0-1.2-.38-1.46-.9h2.9z"></path><path id="clrLamp" fill="#222" d="M6.66.5C3.26.5.5 3.26.5 6.66c0 1.12.3 2.16.82 3.07 1.5 2.72 1.9 4.25 2.16 5.73.2 1.24.5 1.53 1.43 1.53h3.54c.95 0 1.23-.3 1.44-1.57.25-1.48.65-3 2.16-5.73.5-.9.82-1.94.82-3.06C12.86 3.27 10.16.5 6.7.5z"></path></svg></button>
<script>
  const lamp = document.querySelector('#clrLamp');
  const btn = document.querySelector('#bg');
  let lampIsOff = true;
  const change = () => {
    lampIsOff = !lampIsOff; // инвретировать состояние
    lamp.style= lampIsOff ? "" : "fill: rgb(255, 255, 144);"
    document.body.style.background = lampIsOff ? "white" : "#333333"
  }
  btn.addEventListener('click', change, false )
</script>
</body>
```

Без тега `script`

```html
<body>
        <button
          id="bg"
          onclick="
            var lamp = document.querySelector('#clrLamp');
            var isLampOff = !!lamp.style.cssText
            lamp.style = (isLampOff ? '' : 'fill: rgb(255, 255, 144)');
            document.body.style.background = (isLampOff ? 'white' : '#333333');"
          style="
            background-color: rgb(140, 140, 140);
            left: 1em;
            padding: 0.5em;
            top: 1em;
            opacity: 0.8;
            display: inline-block;
            position: fixed;
            height: 3.5em;
            width: 3.5em;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            z-index: 100;
            margin: 0;
            border: 0;
            outline: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
          "
        >
          <svg style="height: 2.5em;" viewBox="0 0 13.31 23" version="1">
            <path
              fill="#fff"
              d="M8.86 18.43c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.3v-.3c0-.18-.12-.32-.28-.32h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.18-.28.35v.3c0 .17.12.3.28.3zm0 1.34c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.3v-.3c0-.18-.12-.32-.28-.32h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.14-.28.3v.3c0 .18.12.32.28.32zm0 1.37c.16 0 .28-.14.28-.32v-.3c0-.16-.12-.3-.28-.3h-4.4c-.16 0-.28.14-.28.3v.3c0 .18.12.32.28.32zm-.76.46c-.25.53-.8.9-1.44.9-.63 0-1.2-.38-1.46-.9h2.9z"
            ></path>
            <path
              id="clrLamp"
              fill="#222"
              d="M6.66.5C3.26.5.5 3.26.5 6.66c0 1.12.3 2.16.82 3.07 1.5 2.72 1.9 4.25 2.16 5.73.2 1.24.5 1.53 1.43 1.53h3.54c.95 0 1.23-.3 1.44-1.57.25-1.48.65-3 2.16-5.73.5-.9.82-1.94.82-3.06C12.86 3.27 10.16.5 6.7.5z"
            ></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </body>
```

Comment: Ого!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Спасибо огромное! ничего себе вы профи!
Только я делаю сайт на Wordpres - и мне нужен код Html для виджета!
Возможно что-нибудь придумать?

Comment: я с вордпрессом не работаю, не знаю какие там ограничения

Comment: скрипт можно вставить в html от этого сильно ничего не поменяется, если нужно могу переделать только под html верстку

Comment: ПОЖАЛУЙСТА ПЕРЕДЕЛАЙТЕ!

Comment: стили тоже можно прописать внутри тегов

Comment: @Андрей `<img style="border-radius: 50%" src="https://i.imgur.com/IO3U1Zj.png">` xD

Comment: вот поэтому и не работаю)) хорошо переделаю

Comment: Я еще не решил с цветами, пожалуйста пропишите в HTML

Comment: добавил вторым снипетом

Comment: Даниил, Не знаю почему но ошибка((

Comment: еще один сниппет сделаю без тега скрипт

Comment: готово, думаю это последнее что я могу придумать по этому поводу)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример такой кнопки.

При клике на неё лампочка погасает, при повторном клике зажигается. (Картинки не смог по лучше найти, тут уж сами :) )

```js
let isLight = true;
function swapStatus() {
    isLight = !isLight;
  let element = document.getElementById("btn");
  if(isLight)
        btn.style.backgroundImage =  "url('https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/317/PNG/128/light-bulb-icon_34400.png')";      
  else btn.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/125/125801.png')"; 
}
```

```css
.button {
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 4px 2px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-image: url(https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/317/PNG/128/light-bulb-icon_34400.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<button class="button" id="btn" onclick="swapStatus()">
</button>
```